# mallinfo doesn't show mmap allocation's information

Tags: c, linux, malloc, mmap

In mallinfo structure there are two fields `hblks` and `hblkhd`. The man documentation says that they are responsible for the number of blocks allocated by mmap and the total number of bytes. But when I run next code

```
void * ptr = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
*(int *) ptr = 10;
```

Fields `hblks` and `hblkhd` are also zero. While the total number of free bytes in the blocks decreases. Could you please explain why this behavior is observed?

I also tried to allocate all free space and use mmap after it. But in this situation fields also equal to zero

Compiler: gcc 9.4.0
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: ```C``` and ```C++``` are two different languages.  Choose the right tag.

Comment: From the man page: *"Note that not all allocations are visible to these functions. Consider using malloc_info(3) instead."* *"Information is returned for only the main memory allocation area.
Allocations in other arenas are excluded."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experiments and they led me to the conclusion that this field is filled only when `mmap` occurred when calling `malloc`. A normal `mmap` call doesn't show up in this statistic, which is logical, because this is a system call, and the statistic is collected in user-space

Comment: Did you find anything to back this up? How is calling ```mmap``` directly or through a helper function (```malloc``` is usually implemented with ```mmap``` these days) any different?

Comment: @Haris, `malloc` keeps track of the memory in the user space. If there is not enough memory, it can use system call `mmap`, but unlike calling `mmap` directly, it will write the call to its stats.

To use my example. 
1) We need to use up the available memory on the heap.
2) Allocate number of bytes larger than `MMAP_THRESHOLD`.
In this case, the fields will not be zero, which I was asking about